# First-order homogenous linear ODE in 2 functions, with information about initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What can be done about the following differential equation:

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} + \frac{dR}{dt} +bR = 0
$$
with:
$$
t\geq0\\
R(0) = 0 \\
P(k) + R(k)=\frac{1}{2}P(0)
$$

Any suggestions? Thank you.

This is a simplification of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795232/saying-something-about-model-parameters-knowing-the-half-life-of-total-protein. It was obtained by adding eqs. 1 & 2, so that the first two terms in the RHS cancel.

Comment: Hi. Can you show a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is easier to help you! Also any reference would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem that I can separate the variables, so I actually have no idea what to do. I have started reviewing the theory on DEs.
I have obtained the equation by adding eqs. 1 and 2 from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795232/saying-something-about-model-parameters-knowing-the-half-life-of-total-protein .

Comment: Technically $P = k$ and $R = c_1 e^{-bt}$ is a solution.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions because you have more unknowns than equations.

Answer (score 0):

Set $$\frac{dP}{dt} = -bR.$$

$$\frac{dR}{dt} = 0$$

The solution is $R = k_1$ and $P = -bRt+ c_1 = -bk_1t + c_1$ by separation of variables. Here $k_1, c_1$ are integration constants.

Set

$$\frac{dR}{dt} = -bR.$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = 0$$

The solution is $R = c_2e^{-bt}$ and $P = k_2$.